# Backup MySql database with PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database, backup

I have a pretty large db in MySql, and I need to take backups of it every day or so.

I need to be able to take backups from any computer, so therefore I thought about making a php script to do this and put this php script online (offcourse with password protection and authorization etc so that only I can access it).

I wonder however, how is this done properly?

What commands should I use, and is it possible to change settings of the backup (for instance `Add AUTO_INCREMENT value = true`)?

I would appreciate examples...

Also, if this is a bad method (unsafe, or maybe gives bad backups with bad sql files), what other method would be preferred?
I have shell-access and I have a VPS (ubuntu server).

My Mysql version is 5.1

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need to involve PHP in the database backup.  You just need a script that uses [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) to backup the database, and [setup a CRON job](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) to periodically execute the script:

```
mysqldump db_name > backup-file.sql
```

...will backup your database to a file, by redirecting the output from the mysqldump to the specified file name.

Peter brought up a good point, that the command would only give you one day of archiving--any archive over two days old would be overwritten.  This would allow you have a rolling log going back seven days:

```
CURRENT_DAY_OF_WEEK=`date '+%u'`
FILENAME="mysqlbackup_"$CURRENT_DAY_OF_WEEK".sql"

mysqldump db_name > $FILENAME
```

Also be aware that file permissions will apply - can't write a file if the user executing the script doesn't have permissions to the folder.

Comment: Of course you probably shouldn't over write the same file every day. Maybe tack on the current date to the file name or some such....

Answer (score 0):

I agree with OMG Ponies mysqldump + script is the way to go.

The only other option that I use is to set up a slave server. This provides an almost instant backup against hardware failure and can be located in a different building to your main server. Unless you have a large number of writes to the database, you don't necessarily need a very powerful server as it is not processing queries, only database updates.