# PHP download backup of MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, download, backup

I want to give a client the ability to manually download a backup of his database. I am coding the site using PHP and MySQL. So after the admin user has logged in there would be a link in the menu to download a .sql file to the local computer. How can I accomplish this with PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595976/backup-mysql-database-with-php is similar

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Backup a mysql database and download as a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751069/backup-a-mysql-database-and-download-as-a-file), and half the questions in the Related list on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can get messy trying to back up a database from PHP, you would be better of letting MySql handle this, and the best way to tell mysql to do this is with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Shell script to backup MySql database
# To backup Nysql databases file to /backup dir and later pick up by your
# script. You can skip few databases from backup too.
# For more info please see (Installation info):
# http://www.cyberciti.biz/nixcraft/vivek/blogger/2005/01/mysql-backup-script.html
# Last updated: Aug - 2005
# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# This is a free shell script under GNU GPL version 2.0 or above
# Copyright (C) 2004, 2005 nixCraft project
# Feedback/comment/suggestions : http://cyberciti.biz/fb/
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# This script is part of nixCraft shell script collection (NSSC)
# Visit http://bash.cyberciti.biz/ for more information.
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

MyUSER="SET-MYSQL-USER-NAME"     # USERNAME
MyPASS="SET-PASSWORD"       # PASSWORD
MyHOST="localhost"          # Hostname

# Linux bin paths, change this if it can not be autodetected via which command
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
CHOWN="$(which chown)"
CHMOD="$(which chmod)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

# Backup Dest directory, change this if you have someother location
DEST="/backup"

# Main directory where backup will be stored
MBD="$DEST/mysql"

# Get hostname
HOST="$(hostname)"

# Get data in dd-mm-yyyy format
NOW="$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")"

# File to store current backup file
FILE=""
# Store list of databases
DBS=""

# DO NOT BACKUP these databases
IGGY="test"

[ ! -d $MBD ] && mkdir -p $MBD || :

# Only root can access it!
$CHOWN 0.0 -R $DEST
$CHMOD 0600 $DEST

# Get all database list first
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS -Bse 'show databases')"

for db in $DBS
do
    skipdb=-1
    if [ "$IGGY" != "" ];
    then
    for i in $IGGY
    do
        [ "$db" == "$i" ] && skipdb=1 || :
    done
    fi

    if [ "$skipdb" == "-1" ] ; then
    FILE="$MBD/$db.$HOST.$NOW.gz"
    # do all inone job in pipe,
    # connect to mysql using mysqldump for select mysql database
    # and pipe it out to gz file in backup dir :)
        $MYSQLDUMP -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
    fi
done
```

and then you tell php to tell the operating system to execute this script and wait for it to be done, this is usually done with `exec` or `system` such as:

```
exec('/path/to/backup/script.sh');
```

Then you can simply send the file created by the script to the browser for that user.

Comment: +1 letting MySQL do it is the way to go. The important thing to take away from the script above is the use of  `mysqldump`. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html for more reference.

Comment: the shell script seem's the best solution as you have more control over errors etc, if you just used `mysqldump` with `exec` then you would more than likely going to run into some error's along the way.

Comment: Thanks this set me on the right track but i made my own shell script to execute the mysqldump command

Comment: That's perfectly fine, and hope i have shared some good knowledge with you :)

Comment: This is plagiarism. every single word is copied from http://bash.cyberciti.biz/backup/backup-mysql-database-server-2/ and not a single credit to the original author. what a shame.