# mysql database backup by a single click with php

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP download backup of MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641612/php-download-backup-of-mysql-database)

I want a one click database backup. backup can be saved as .sql or .zip or .txt file in a folder which I define.

Comment: look into the mysqldump program

Comment: my program runs in localhost(windows/xampp). how can I do this?

Comment: Click? Why do you want to have to click? If you're backing up - which is good - you want to do it regularly so automate it.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing in my C# app and started a console call of mysqldump like this:

```
mysqldump -u username --password=yourpass db_name > outputfile.sql
```

Answer (score -2):

You can backup database or tables using [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net)