# PHP perform backup of all database actions in realtime

Tags: php, mysql, backup

After loosing one days data by accidentially doing a "TRUNCATE TABLE" I'm now looking for a solution to perform a realtime backup of all important database actions (Insert, Update + Delete). What would be the best way also performance-wise?

My approach so far:

```
function db_query($sql) {
    if(strlen(stristr($sql,'insert '))!=0 OR strlen(stristr($sql,'update '))!=0 OR strlen(stristr($sql,'delete '))!=0 ){
        $date = date("Ymd"); //get todays date  
        $fh = fopen($date."sql.txt", 'a'); // open file, if not exist -> create
        fwrite($fh, addslashes($sql)."\n"); // write at the end of file
    }
    return mysql_query($sql);
}

db_query("INSERT INTO mytable (nr,text) values ('example','example')");
```

Comment: this might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595976/backup-mysql-database-with-php?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, but that's all about doing whole database backups periodically through cronjobs. With this approach you still loose the data between those backups, I don't wanna have these "gaps".

Comment: replication is the word you are looking for